# Relative Path, but for Port?

Tags: http, url, port, relative-path

We are all familiar with relative paths: A relative path to `./images/hello.jpg` from `http://www.domain.com/hey` links to `http://www.domain.com/hey/images/hello.jpg`.

**Problem:** How do you state a relative path to `http://www.domain.com:1234` when you are at `http://www.domain.com/hey`?

Comment: I don't think you can. The port is effectively part of the domain name in this context. By specifying the domain name without the port (not using a relative link) you are basically supplying a _different_ domain.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6016120/60075

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This can be achieved using JavaScript by setting the `window.location.port` property.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.location.port=8080">go</a>
```

Comment: sure... but only in JavaScript. Try to make a relative StyleSheet-path for instance

Comment: Not 100% sure of which context the question applies, but given the question I guess you could also serve the CSS from the same port. Then relative paths will be relative.

Comment: This only works if `href` contains only an anchor. See [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13522508/60075) which has a similar solution but should work for other hrefs too. That is, modify `event.target.port` rather than `window.location.port`.

Answer (score 24):

You cannot change any part of the *authority* (i.e. the *host:port* part) in relative URLs.
See the algorithm described in [section 5.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.2) of [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) to see how relative URLs are interpreted. Important thing to notice is that authority is simply copied from base URL or from the URL being resolved and authority's structure is never interpreted. This implies that you cannot change any of its parts, including the port part.

Here's the algorithm in pseudo-code copied from the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986):

```
  -- The URI reference is parsed into the five URI components
  --
  (R.scheme, R.authority, R.path, R.query, R.fragment) = parse(R);

  -- A non-strict parser may ignore a scheme in the reference
  -- if it is identical to the base URI's scheme.
  --
  if ((not strict) and (R.scheme == Base.scheme)) then
     undefine(R.scheme);
  endif;

  if defined(R.scheme) then
     T.scheme    = R.scheme;
     T.authority = R.authority;
     T.path      = remove_dot_segments(R.path);
     T.query     = R.query;
  else
     if defined(R.authority) then
        T.authority = R.authority;
        T.path      = remove_dot_segments(R.path);
        T.query     = R.query;
     else
        if (R.path == "") then
           T.path = Base.path;
           if defined(R.query) then
              T.query = R.query;
           else
              T.query = Base.query;
           endif;
        else
           if (R.path starts-with "/") then
              T.path = remove_dot_segments(R.path);
           else
              T.path = merge(Base.path, R.path);
              T.path = remove_dot_segments(T.path);
           endif;
           T.query = R.query;
        endif;
        T.authority = Base.authority;
     endif;
     T.scheme = Base.scheme;
  endif;

  T.fragment = R.fragment;
```

Comment: Thanks for a definitive answer on this issue!

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: **not possible**.
You need to use an absolute path if the host changes.

Answer (score -5):

Simply you can write in href attribute:

```
/:port/[path/]file.ext
```