# CSS, Relative path and URL portnumber

Tags: css, url-routing

i got this stylesheet that is inside my   tags of a webpage. (not a css-file because this is the only file it will ever be used in).

```
background-image: url("/assets/img/report/test4.png");
```

My background-image url doesnt include the port number for the host when using relative url.

Example:

Works:

```
localhost:8334/assets/img/report/test4.png
```

Does not work, and is the output of relative url:

```
localhost/assets/img/report/test4.png
```

Any idea why its not including the port number?

Comment: You contradict yourself in this question. "background-image does not load when using port numbers in the url." then you say `localhost:8334` works but `localhost` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Andy, i added a hopefully better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If your 'assets' folder is in the root why are you adding the extra '/' ? I've never used it like this, try editing it out perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `relative` path rather than an `absolute` one. Example:

`background-image:url('../../assets/img/report/test4.png');`

Comment: I am using a relative path, url("/assets/img/report/test4.png"); 

Absolute paths are including the host aswell url("localhost:8080/assets/img/report/test4.png") would be a absolute path.

Comment: My suggestion was to avoid the use of absolute paths. However, your answer may be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317059/relative-path-but-for-port.

or here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016120/relative-url-to-a-different-port-number-in-a-hyperlink

It seems that you cannot avoid the use of js.