# Create an HTML link to a file in another port?

Tags: html

The tag below ceates a link to a page without having to provide the full URL:

```
<a href="foo.html">link</a>
```

So if you click it from `example.com/`, you'll go to `example.com/foo.html`. Is there a way to create a link that'll go to `example.com:port/foo.html` instead?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016120/relative-url-to-a-different-port-number-in-a-hyperlink) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317059/relative-path-but-for-port)?

Comment: does this not work? <a href="example.com:8080/foo.html">link</a>

Comment: Elephant - I think Dokkat is after a relative link not an absolute link. That way the code is portable across servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/6016361/773263

```
// delegate event for performance,
// and save attaching a million events to each anchor
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a')
  {
      var port = target.getAttribute('href')
                       .match(/^:(\d+)$/);
      if (port)
      {
         target.port = port[1];
      }
  }
}, false);
```

Seems to be the best way to do it. I don't think a purely HTML solution is possible.