# HTML specify src with different port

Tags: javascript, html, src

```
<html>
    <body>
         <audio src="PinkNoise.ogg" controls autoplay loop></audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to specify the `src` to this file with a different port, like such:

```
<audio src=":8009/PinkNoise.ogg" controls autoplay loop></audio>
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work, as it resolves to:
`<the url>/:8009/PinkNoise.ogg`

I'm using a javascript hack to just get the `window` location and then tacking on a different port. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: "I'm using a javascript hack" Can we see it?

Comment: You are going to have to use JavaScript to set it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016120/relative-url-to-a-different-port-number-in-a-hyperlink