# Is there a way to make a hyperlink run code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with getting links to work. Links can launch things, such as

```
javascript:x=document.createElement("script");x.src="https://worldlanguages.github.io/animatedThumbnailsBookmarklet/code.js"; void document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(x);
```

That works and can launch a script. I am trying to make a colorpicker, but I don't understand why it's not working. Below is my code.

```
javascript:x=document.createElement("script");x.src="//raw.githubusercontent.com/hellolose/Color-Picker/master/.gitignore/.gitignore"; void document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(x);
```

It can find the code but It won't  launch. I don't know which went wrong, the code or the actual launching. If there are answers, could you please post them in the comments, and if this is already answered then I didn't find it. The ones I found all had answers. : ( Thanks!

Comment: Your src URL (`src="//raw.githubusercontent.com/...`) looks like it is missing the `https:` part.

Comment: @RobJarvis  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265762/scheme-relative-url

Comment: Might better to reword as 'run code from a URL'. Good question though

Comment: Good info, @Quentin. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the `src` attribute of a `<script>` element needs to be a URL pointing to a JavaScript program.

The URL you are providing has `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` in the headers (this is **not** a JavaScript Content-Type so it will be stopped by security checks in most browsers) and the content of the file starts with `<html lang="en">` so it isn't a JavaScript program anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the same thing with some JS:

```
<script>
var hyperlink = document.getElementById("YOUR HYPERLINK ID");

hyperlink.addEventListener("click", displayWheel)

function displayWheel(){
\\ Add all your code here
}
</script>
```

Also make sure that the `<a>` tag has the value for the `href="#"`