# How do I do a href to port?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

How do I do a href to port?

I have tried:

```
 <li><a href=":8123">Earth</a></li>
```

This resulst in directing me to localhost/:8123
I want to be directed to localhost:8123

This works, but not for the local enviorment:

```
<li><a href="wwww.nordicreservation.com:8123">Earth</a></li>
```

Don't want to just use the second one because I find it rather hard to search for errors if I can not use the local computer to test the site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative URL to a different port number in a hyperlink?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016120/relative-url-to-a-different-port-number-in-a-hyperlink)

Comment: why not use the 2nd one?

Comment: You'll need `http://` in front of an absolute link

Comment: That does not seem right, because whenver I access the site remotely this works:

    <li><a href="wwww.nordicreservation.com:8123">Earth</a></li>
I just need it to work on a local level too, since :8123 manages to add a / in front of the :

Comment: just add `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` to the url before the port. check they dont have the port already

Comment: Dagon, please write the whole string I am suposed to use...
I wrote:

    <li><a href="$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:8123">Earth</a></li>
This directed me to: http://localhost/nordicreservation/$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']:8123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the local domain\host use one of the php server variables either: 
`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` or `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

IE:

```
<li><a href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>:8123">Earth</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do with javascript:

```
<li><a id="Earth">Earth</a>
<script>
document.getElementById('Earth').href=''+window.location.origin+':8124';
</script>
```