# How set href in html <a> tag

Tags: javascript, php

Let's I have two server running on my PC. **server1** and **server2**....

1. In server1 there is a html page.(ex. a.html)
2. In server2 there is another html page.(ex b.html)
3. Server1 is running on port 80
4. Server2 is running on port 8080

In a.html of server1 there is a  tag.
Now I want to access b.html from server2 by the above link that's why I have written

```
<a href="localhost:8080/b.html">
```

It's working really well if I access a.html and click that link working fine in my computer where both servers are running.

......  I want to access a.html from server1 in my phone. My pc and phone both are in the same wifi network.

To solve this problem I opened my phone browser and gave my pc ip ex. ***192.168.0.1/a.html***

It's working fine.
 But as I said in above that there is a link in that page (ex given above).
When I click on that link it's giving error

> This site can't be reached
>   localhost refused to connect

.... I know where is the problem . The problem is in the link because I explicitly wrote ***localhost:8080*** . Here is the problem.
I should write my pc private it instead of localhost then it'll work I know. But how to get my private IP by javascript to modify the link dynamically by javascript.

Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Make the href relative and omit the port/host. `<a href="a.html">` - This way, the link should "inherit" the host and port number of the current url.

Comment: @evolutionxbox But he wants a different port number so the link goes to the other server

Comment: If that's the case, then the link should be `<a href="192.168.0.1:8080/b.html">` - You can't get away from using the ip address. You can't use localhost.

Comment: @evolutionxbox So finally we are back to his actual question. __But how to get my private IP by javascript to modify the link dynamically by javascript__

Comment: `location.hostname` this will be `localhost` or `192.168.0.1` depending on which url is used to access the server.

Comment: Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016120/relative-url-to-a-different-port-number-in-a-hyperlink) is likely to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

Your phone is basically redirecting to itself.

Your `<a>` tag should look like this:

**in 192.168.0.1/a.html**

```
<a href="192.168.0.1:8080/b.html">
```

or if you prefer not to muddy up your HTML then this also possible

**in 192.168.0.1/a.html**

```
<HTML5>
    <head>
        <base href="192.168.0.1:8080/">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="b.html">b.html on server #2</a>
        <br>
        <a href="192.168.0.1/c.html">c.html on server #1</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `static.ip.server.2`? Is it output by the static sever (static)?

Comment: Interesting, but does this not mean that all `href` links will go to server 2 on this page. That may not be what is required

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, but it can be combated via absolute URLs to itself, though.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The root of the issue is that OP's phone directs localhost requests to itself. OP needs to use a static IP in his `<a>` tags and anything else that points to a server resource.

Comment: Yea I realise that, I was just sticking around to see what sort of solutions people came up with as I was interested

Answer (score 1):

Both servers are running on your pc. So, to access both servers except own pc you need to provide your private ip. This way you can access your both servers.

Now, you,  at first want to access your a.html of server1 where there is a link to b.html of server2.

Don't write **localhost** explicitly.
And you want to change href of the link dynamically.
Follw below step.

1. Change your link of a.html of server1 to `<a id="link" href="#"></a>`
2. You have to change your link dynamically. So to change the link I am using JQuery window.onload() method. Add this script to your code

```js
<script>
  window.onload=function()
{
  //Modify the link href
 var ip=location.host;
 $("a#link").attr("href", "http://"+ip+":8080/b.html");
}
</script>
```

1. Because your server2 is running on port 8080 and has a file named b.html
2. Now you don't need to worry. it'll work on both your pc and another pc or phone in the same network.