# Tag <a> change url and lost the port

Tags: html

- In my code `<a href="x.x.x.x:12345/test">myweb</a>`. When click it,the url change x.x.x.x/test on the browser .The port lost.
- My browser is chrome.I try `<a href="x.x.x.x:12345/test" target="_blank">myweb</a>` ,the new Tab's url has port.But after loading ,it lost the port.

Comment: Are you sure that the server is not redirecting the user from port 12345 to port 80?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016120/relative-url-to-a-different-port-number-in-a-hyperlink

Comment: @VivekAthalye It is sure.The new opening tab's url is x.x.x.x/test and there is not port 12345.