# script src using relative path and a different port

Tags: javascript, html

There are all sorts of great ways to [have an href with a relative path and different port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016120/relative-url-to-a-different-port-number-in-a-hyperlink) on click, but I can't find anything to do the same for a `<script>`'s `src` attribute.

How can I approximate this?

```
<script src=":8000/same/host/different/port.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why not create the script tag on the go, from the example you’ve linked to, and address the port and path to the script in the same manner? E.g. create script element, set the src and append to body?

Comment: Does it have to be client side?

Comment: @MinusFour the server side context is a very small step above a static web page, so in this case I believe yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Cue made me realize there is a solution in the linked question, using [Craig McQueen's second suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13522508/1013719), I can get the path.

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
const scriptSrc = (window.location.protocol + '//' + 
                   window.location.hostname + 
                   ':8000/same/host/different/port.js');
script.setAttribute('src', scriptSrc);
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: In this scenario, can we guarantee that the javascript in port.js will be executed before it continues parsing the rest of the page? I believe that if using a classic <script> tag it would just wondering if the behaviour would be the same?

Comment: @MaxCarroll I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "before it continues parsing." Could you explain the problem that you are trying to avoid?